# C# / .net GET unexpected behaviour

Tags: c#, .net, webclient, http-get, httpwebresponse

Doing a simple GET from C#

```
var webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.Headers.Add("Accept", "*.*");
webClient.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
webClient.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "runscope/0.1");
var response = webClient.DownloadString("http://booking.frederiksberg.dk/NetInterBook/SearchScheme/SimpleSearch.aspx");
```

I get a response that is different than the same thing executed from Chrome's Advanced Rest Client / Postman / http://Hurl.it

I still get a website, but it doesn't contain the form information that I am looking for (the items with id-s similar to this drplFacility_item_1).

I've tried using RestSharp and HttpWebResponse as well, with the same results. What am I not doing that these other HTTP clients are? According to Chrome's network tab, they seem to be doing pretty vanilla GET-s. Thanks!

Here's the page I get from the webclient: http://pastebin.com/5PjxejKT

Comment: Why do you have several spaces on your url "http://booking.frederiksberg.dk/NetInterBook/Sea    rchScheme"?

Comment: What is that long space in the URL?

Comment: Copy paste mistake apparently, I don't have it in the original code of course.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/5PjxejKT This is what I'm getting from my webclient.

Comment: What do you mean by it does not contain `drplFacility_item_1`. It is there in that page.

Comment: There are tons of the same questions: my request made with XXX does not match browser/some other tool. Answer is always the same - compare request and figure out differences. There is nothing SO can help you with. (Note that search for tools to do that would be off-topic, so just use Fiddler like everyone else)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Yeah, I did that before posting, and there were no differences. See my answer for more details...

Comment: @user3616457 good you've found the answer (no way SO would've helped you the way question stands now). Note that if you listed what you've tried (especially the fact you already compared responses with WireShark) the question could be received more positively. You may want to edit title of your post in a way that could have helped you to find solution - there is no way one would fined this problem via search due to very generic title.

Answer (score 1):

It was a Visual Studio GUI bug that was tripping me up. I did use inspectors before posting this question, and I was just really baffled as to why I'm getting a different response for the same GET from .NET then everywhere else. Turns out, I wasn't. (Thanks WireShark!)

Here's the active bug report: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2016177/text-visualizer-misses-corrupts-text-in-long-strings

Hope this helps anyone who might come across this, it took me a long time to figure this one out...